# HERE SDK turn-by-turn navigation maneuvers

Tags: android, here-api

In the HERE SDK user guide there is a screenshot showing the next maneuver. See:

https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/map-guidance.html

Is this something that is provided by the SDK or is the developer expected to render this manually?

Here is the navigation code I am using:

```
                    Route route = list.get(0).getRoute();

                map.setMapScheme(Map.Scheme.CARNAV_DAY);
                map.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);
                map.setTilt(45);
                map.addMapObject(new MapRoute(route));
                manager.setRoute(route);
                manager.setTrafficAvoidanceMode(NavigationManager.TrafficAvoidanceMode.DYNAMIC);

                manager.setRealisticViewMode(NavigationManager.RealisticViewMode.DAY);
                manager.setMap(map);
                NavigationManager.Error simError = manager.startNavigation(route);
                if(simError != NavigationManager.Error.NONE) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error" + simError);
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things are rendered automatically by the HERE SDK, mainly things that are directly tied to the map rendering (like navigation arrows on the street when doing guidance), but most UI things you have to do on your own since most users want to have their own look&feel and UI.

So, yes the maneuver icons are something you have to provide and render in your UI manually (or the other way around: you have the full freedom to decide how it should look like).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit late, but for the others who are having the same question,
You can use the HERE Mobile SDK UI Kit (MSDKUI) which provides a highly customizable user interface components that can be used on top of the HERE SDKs.

Here is the repo on Github:
https://github.com/heremaps/msdkui-android